# How to archive an entire IMAP account?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a couple of IMAP accounts that are no longer active, but I still need to access some of these old messages.  I know that I can create a subfolder under "Local Folder" and then individually move each message to the subfolder, but each account has 20K+ message so this is not realistic.  Is a there a more sensible way to do this?  For instance, currently these IMAP files *seems* to be stored in:

```
 .thunderbird/something.default/ImapMail/(name of account)
```

and that the local subfolders I created *seem* to be in:

```
.thunderbird/something.default/Mail/Local_Folders/(name of subfolder)
```

Can I simply  **mv** the IMAP folders to the local folder directories?  Is there *anything/folder/dot-files etc* that I need to move/modify?  These old messages are important so I can't afford to mess up.

In case this matter:  I need to keep the two old IMAP accounts separate.

I do need to need these two IMAP accounts.

Comment: You should make backups https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization

Comment: @rinzwind:  Could you please clarify?  Currently both IMAP accounts are set to (1) "keep messages in all folders for this account on this computer" (2) "synchronize all message locally regardless of age" (3) "don't delete any messages" + "always keep starred messges".   And in case I didn't make myself clear: Both accounts have terminated i.e. I can't connect to the server.

Comment: You should be using regular backups of your `/home/USER` folder. For example, using the default Backup app. You can also make a zip file of the folder where Thunderbird keeps your IMAP emails and keep them in an external drive.

Comment: If you want to copy or move all the emails to a different folder within Thunderbird, Use Ctrl+A to select all (all 20K+) messages and copy/move them to a sub-folder of your local folder.